# interrupting scroll to animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a page where all the content is in one page and clicking in a link on the navbar does a scroll animation to the relevant section. Code pen is http://codepen.io/meek/pen/NNprYb?editors=0010

I'm using the following code for the scroll animation:

```
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

    var target = $(this.hash);

    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

My question is whether there is a way to cancel this animation when the user clicks another section while the animation is still playing. At the moment it completes the previous animation and adds the next one to a "queue", meaning that if you spam click different sections you get stuck in animations you can't cancel out of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just add this code before the animate():

```
$('html, body').stop();
```